# create new dataframe using function

Tags: python, function, heatmap

I ran into this nice blogpost : https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1c.

The author creates a function that allows you to calculate associations between categorical features and then create a heatmap out of it.

The function is given as:

```
def cramers_v(x, y):
    confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(x,y)
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2-((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))
    rcorr = r-((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k-((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr/min((kcorr-1),(rcorr-1)))
```

I am able to create a list of associations between one feature and the rest by running the function in a for loop.

```
for item in raw[categorical].columns.tolist():
  value = cramers_v(raw['status_group'], raw[item])
  print(item, value)
```

It works in the sense that I get a list of association values
[image]

but I don't know how I would run this function for all features against eachother and turn that into a new dataframe.
[image]

The author of this article has written a nice new library that has this feature built in, but it doesn't turn out nicely for my long list of features (my laptop can't handle it).

Running it on the first 100 lines of my df results in this... (note: this is what I get by running the associations function of the dython library written by the author).
[image]

How could I run the cramers_v function for all combinations of features and then turn this into a df which I could display in a heatmap?

Comment: Brenda can you paste png, that'd help us understand what you mean by "doesn't turn out nicely for my long list of features". What exactly do you want to change in your current generated heatmap

Comment: Hi, I have have updated my question :)